# Read all keys and values of dynamic JSON array into table in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have got a JSON like this.

```
{[{id:1,Name:'alex',age:10},{id:2,Name:'John',age:20}...]}
```

So my requirement is to create a table like this

```
id    Name    Age
-------------------
1     Alex    10
2     John    20
-----------------
```

If always the JSON is the same I can just create an interface like this and can use the array

```
export interface Details{
   id:number;
   Name:string;
   Age:number;
}
```

But my concern is JSON will be different. So we cant always can define whats the JSON data structure

Which means sometimes the JSON will be

```
[{School:'School1', City:'East Ham',Students:2000},{School:'School2', City:'Whitechapel',Students:3000}]
```

and the table will be

```
School      City     Students
------------------------------
School1    East Ham    2000
School2    Whitechapel 3000
------------------------------------
```

So any kind of Data will come, but its totally different.

So how can handle that situation to generate a table like this

```
<table>

    <thead>
      <tr><th *ngFor="let item of headers:let index=index">{{item}}</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of data"><td *ngFor="let col of row">{{col}}</td></tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

There wont be any idea how the data will be. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 14px;">
  <tr>
    <th style="text-transform: capitalize; border: 1px solid black; padding: 8px;" 
      *ngFor="let item of yourData[0] | keyvalue">
      {{ item.key }}
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let a of yourData | keyvalue">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let b of a.value | keyvalue">
      <td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 8px;">
        {{ b.value }}
      </td>
    </ng-container>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Where `yourData` is your json response data.